# Data formula to work out 3 scenarios from one value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Please help! :) Here is my data:

```
state = {
        data: [
            createData('23 May 2017', 'Seniors', 'Brazil', '90 mins', '3:0'),
            createData('14 May 2017', 'Seniors', 'Italy', '45 mins', '0:0'),
            createData('14 Nov 2016', 'Seniors', 'Germany', '0 mins', '0:2')
        ],
    };`
```

The value I am interested in is the score e.g `'3:0'` this would be a home win so I need a formula to give the result `'won'` see the 3 scenarios below:

if first value > second = won

if first value = second = drew

if first value < second = loss

I then use the result of won, lost or drew to feed my const

```
const statusStyle = result.includes("Won") ? "text-white bg-success" : result.includes("Drew") ? "bg-amber" : result.includes("Lost") ? "text-white bg-danger" : "text-white bg-grey";
```

I have _lodash if this can be used to get turn the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the score (`3:0` for example) by the `:` sign, and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to two consts, then compare the consts:

```js
const getGameResult = (score) => {
  const [a, b] = score.split(':');
  
  if(a > b) return 'won';
  
  if(a < b) return 'lost';
  
  return 'draw';
}

console.log(getGameResult('3:0')); // won
console.log(getGameResult('0:0')); // draw
console.log(getGameResult('0:2')); // lost
```